how to write data from data bricks to ADLS
how to write data from data bricks to ADLS ?
Ans :
dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://transformed-data@azuredatalakegen2project.dfs.core.windows.net/")

customer_df.coalesce(1)write.format("csv").option("sep", "|").save("abfss://transformed-data@azuredatalakegen2project.dfs.core.windows.net/customer")

dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://transformed-data@azuredatalakegen2project.dfs.core.windows.net/")

customer_df.coalesce(1)write.format("csv").option("sep", "|").save("abfss://transformed-data@azuredatalakegen2project.dfs.core.windows.net/customer")


Try This
dbutils.fs.ls("abfss://transformed-data@azuredatalakegen2project.dfs.core.windows.net/")
customer.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("sep", "|").save("abfss://transformed-data@azuredatalakegen2project.dfs.core.windows.net/customer")

what is the problem you are facing. add more details.


how to write data from data bricks to ADLS ?

You can follow below procedure to write data from data bricks to ADLS:
Mount the ADLS gen2 account using below code:
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source="wasbs://<containerName>@<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point="/mnt/<mountName>",
    extra_configs={
f"fs.azure.account.key.<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net":"<Access-Key>"  
  }
)

Write dataframe into ADLS using below code with mount point:
customer_df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("sep", "|").save('/mnt/<mountName>/customer')

Here is the sample dataframe to write it to ADLS:
from pyspark.sql import Row

data = [
    Row(CustomerID=1, Name="AA", Age=34, Country="USA"),
    Row(CustomerID=2, Name="BB", Age=45, Country="UK"),
    Row(CustomerID=3, Name="Charlie", Age=29, Country="Canada"),
    Row(CustomerID=4, Name="David", Age=32, Country="Australia"),
    Row(CustomerID=5, Name="Eva", Age=41, Country="Germany")
]  
customer_df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

customer_df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("sep", "|").save('/mnt/files/customer')

The dataframe will write to ADLS successfully as shown below:

